# RoboVM - Error on building workspace

Tags: java, android, ios, macos, robovm

I am trying to set up an ios version of my android app, and have been told to use RoboVM. I have installed the plugin, but I keep getting an error on the build.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'RoboVM Class Builder' on project 'IOSDemo'.
Could not initialize class org.robovm.llvm.Target
```

Im really not sure what is causing this.. Ive done everything correctly on my part. Could someone tell me whats going on?

One thing I was thinking is possibly because I dont have a mac?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? But anyway - yes, you need a Mac in order to build the app.

Comment: Also see the documentation here: http://www.robovm.org/docs#start
It clearly states, that you need a Mac with Xcode 5+